# Losing Binding / Object reference when binding Popup.IsOpen to an ObservableCollection through IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, popup

currently i'm trying to bind the Popup.IsOpen property to an ObservableCollection through an IValueConverter, determining if the collection has items (true) or not(false).

Problem:
IValueConverter is only fired once at initializing the application and then never again.

View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AutoCompleteTextBox.Views.AutoCompleteTextBoxView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AutoCompleteTextBox.Views"
             xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:AutoCompleteTextBox.Converter"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:AutoCompleteTextBox.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converter:CollectionHasItemsToBooleanConverter x:Key="collectionHasItemsToBoolean" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewmodels:AutoCompleteTextBoxViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox 
            Name="txtSearchBox"            
            Text="{Binding SearchString,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
        <Popup 
            IsOpen="{Binding UserCollection,
            Converter={StaticResource collectionHasItemsToBoolean},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
            Width="{Binding ElementName=txtSearchBox,Path=ActualWidth}"
            PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=txtSearchBox}">
            <ListView 
                ItemsSource="{Binding UserCollection,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=OneWay}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=OneWay}">
                        </Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class AutoCompleteTextBoxViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string searchString;

    public string SearchString
    {
        get { return searchString; }
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref searchString, value))
            {
                if (UserCollection.Count == 3) UserCollection.Clear();
                if (searchString != string.Empty)
                {
                    UserCollection.Add(new UserModel() { Name = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<UserModel> UserCollection { get; set; }
    public AutoCompleteTextBoxViewModel()
    {
        UserCollection = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>();            
    }
}
```

Details:
Class BindableBase implements INotifyPropertChanged, is fired by using SetProperty inside the setter of a property.
While setting PopUp.IsOpen manually to true, the desired popup is working.
Binding PopUp.IsOpen to ObservableCollection.Count works (with customized IValueConverter for checking int values).

Does anyone see the error i am currently missing or some hints?

Have a nice weekend!

Daniel

Comment: I believe the problem is that when you are making changes to UserCollection only CollectionChanged is fired and this one won't trigger update. You would have to fire PropertyChanged with the name of UserCollection from your VM for it to trigger.

Comment: If you want an actual answer, you need to provide a better question. Include a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, and explain in detail what you've done so far to try to debug the problem. I will point out that your use of `UpdateSourceTrigger` and `Mode=TwoWay` seems wrong. If the pop-up visibility changes, what do you expect your converter to do with that? What _does_ it do with that? Also, per the previous comment, your binding needs to be to something that would change, such as the `Count` property. Please improve your question.

Comment: @CrudaLilium 
Thanks a lot!!!
Firing an PropertyChanged event inside my VM showed exact the behaviour you described.
Adding/deleting of elements inside a collection does obviously not fire a propertychanged event for the collection itself so i have to fire it explicitly.

Hope you have a nice evening and thanks for your help!

Comment: @CrudaLilium
If you add your comment as answer to my question i will flag it as such :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment from CrudaLilium worked:

"I believe the problem is that when you are making changes to UserCollection only CollectionChanged is fired and this one won't trigger update. You would have to fire PropertyChanged with the name of UserCollection from your VM for it to trigger."